# Adding List of Related IDs to returned values in a Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

According to the example in [Django's Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), I can obtain a list of reverse related objects like this:

```
Blog.objects.values('entry__id')
```

Which would presumably give me the ids of all related Entry objects. If I wanted this information in addition to all the other information returned in a normal `.values()` call, is there a short way to add it on? Or do I need to explicitly list all of the models' fields in `.values()` to have the reverse keys included in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `annotate` to add extra fields from foreign keys

```
from django.db.models import F

blogs = Blog.objects.all().annotate(entry_id=F('entry__id'))

for blog in blogs:
    print(blog.entry_id)
```

Comment: Of course! The F expression that's what I was looking for, thank you